# CATextLayer rotate?

Tags: ios, cocoa, catextlayer

This should really work, but is not:

```
CATextLayer* textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
textLayer.string = @"text";
[textLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI / 2.f forKey:@"transform.rotation"];
[self addSublayer:textLayer];
```

in fact, when i print the value at transform.rotation, it shows the correct answer.  it just doesn't draw the textLayer rotated!

```
NSLog(@"rotation %@", [textLayer valueForKey:@"transform.rotation"]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
textLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2));
```

instead of:

```
[textLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI / 2.f forKey:@"transform.rotation"];
```

Comment: That did it!  Though I still don't get why the other method didn't work.  According to the documentation it really should.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The CALayer will remember any value you give it.  I believe what you have it wrong because you need to rotate with "transform.rotation.z".

Comment: nope... the documentation says that "rotation" is the same as "rotation.z"  i just tried this to make sure... but no luck.