# Rotate CATextLayer with UIInterfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone, rotation, core-animation, calayer, catextlayer

I have a CATextLayer as sublayer of CALayer. The CALayer rotates and so does the CATextLayer as expected. The problem is that that CATextLayer should always face upside down (according to UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait). I have tried rotating the CATextLayer but it shifts positions and moves out of the bounds of it's parent layer. I just want to rotate the CATextLayer such that it is always aligned to the current interface orientation no matter what is the angle of it's parent layer. 
I have tried the answer in this thread but nothing happens [CATextLayer rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269462/catextlayer-rotate)

Comment: Please read this advice on asking good questions: [ask] and [Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/1tBMnR). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Comment: Thanks. I am new at SO. I edited my question.